# Why did I lose 2 reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, lost-reputation

I know it's not anything but I just want to know how I lost that.

So what happened was I had 932. But now I have 930. I checked my reputation log for today but there wasn't anything on downvotes. I checked for answers but there was only 1 deleted answer and that had 0 score.

Comment: @JohnPalmer If I lost reputation based on deleted edit posts, I heard there's 500 edit limit of gaining reputation. So say I had 280 before the deleted post. After the deleted would it count as 279/500 used?

Comment: May be one of very old post got delete on which you have performed `suggested edit`.

Comment: @Vigbyor Oh well I can't really find out though. Too lazy to check through 280+.

Comment: Did you check the "show removed posts" box at the bottom of your reputation page?

Comment: @Troyen I thought you could only earn a total of 1000 rep for edits.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg You're right ([Reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)). It's also linked to the edit privilege which is 1000 rep on beta sites, so I never encountered the lower limit and got confused.

Comment: @Troyen Just hoping that deleted edits don't count towards that lol.